# é possivel juntar uma ou mais colunas que possuem o mesmo id no mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

eu tenho uma tabela clientes, uma tabela colaboradores, produtos, uma tabela de vendas e uma tabela para ligar as vendas com os produtos.
minha duvida é quando faço o select

```
SELECT idvendas,data_da_venda,valortotal,clientes.Nome as cliente,colaboradores.Nome as vendedor, produtos.Nome  from vendas
INNER JOIN produtos_has_vendas ON vendas.idvendas = produtos_has_vendas.vendas_idvendas 
INNER JOIN produtos ON produtos_has_vendas.Produtos_SKU = produtos.SKU
INNER JOIN colaboradores ON colaboradores.idcolaboradores = vendas.colaboradores_idcolaboradores 
INNER JOIN clientes ON clientes.idclientes = vendas.clientes_idclientes 
where data_da_venda >= curdate() and vendas.Usuario_idUsuário = 1
```

ele retorna

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

é possivel "juntar" os dois nomes de produtos da coluna Nome enquanto o idvendas tiver o mesmo valor ?

Tentei Agrupar o id da tabela com group by

```
    SELECT idvendas,data_da_venda,valortotal,clientes.Nome as cliente,colaboradores.Nome as vendedor, produtos.Nome  from vendas
INNER JOIN produtos_has_vendas ON vendas.idvendas = produtos_has_vendas.vendas_idvendas 
INNER JOIN produtos ON produtos_has_vendas.Produtos_SKU = produtos.SKU
INNER JOIN colaboradores ON colaboradores.idcolaboradores = vendas.colaboradores_idcolaboradores 
INNER JOIN clientes ON clientes.idclientes = vendas.clientes_idclientes 
where data_da_venda >= curdate() and vendas.Usuario_idUsuário = 1
group by idvendas
```

retorno
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porem ele retorna apenas um dos nomes de produtos, na coluna de Nome

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT idvendas,
       data_da_venda,
       valortotal,
       clientes.nome      AS cliente,
       colaboradores.nome AS vendedor,
       group_concat(produtos.nome) nomes
  FROM vendas
 INNER JOIN produtos_has_vendas
    ON vendas.idvendas = produtos_has_vendas.vendas_idvendas
 INNER JOIN produtos
    ON produtos_has_vendas.produtos_sku = produtos.sku
 INNER JOIN colaboradores
    ON colaboradores.idcolaboradores = vendas.colaboradores_idcolaboradores
 INNER JOIN clientes
    ON clientes.idclientes = vendas.clientes_idclientes
 WHERE data_da_venda >= curdate()
   AND vendas.usuario_idusuário = 1
 GROUP BY idvendas
```

Veja um exemplo rodando [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/176173).